# Derivation of Green's Function for Wave Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform, greens-functions

In the textbook *Modern Methods in Analytical Acoustics* (Crighton-1992, [Amazon link to 2013 edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540197370)) the following relates the 3D [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function) in the time-domain to the frequency domain $g(x-y)$:
\begin{align}
g\left(\mathbf{x-y}\right)&=-\frac{c^2}{4\pi cr}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta\left(r-ct\right)e^{i\omega t}\,dt,\qquad r=\left|\mathbf{x-y}\right|\\
&=-\frac{1}{4\pi r}e^{ik_0t},\tag{2.158}
\end{align}

I cannot see how the integration has eliminated the variable c. To me the integration should leave $e^{i k_0 r}$ where $k_0=\omega/c$ and then the answer should be
$$
g(\mathbf{x-y}) = -\frac{c}{4 \pi r} e^{i k_0 r}
$$
which I know to be incorrect by a factor of c.

Is the text wrong? And if so, then how do I derive the correct expression for $g(\mathbf{x-y})$?

Note: the $-c^2$ factor is used to relate the Green's function $G(x,y,t) = \frac{\delta(r-ct)}{4 \pi c r}$ for the equation 
$$
(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \nabla^2) G(x,y,t) = \delta |x-y|
$$
to the reduced wave equation:
$$
( \nabla^2 + k_0^2)  G(x,y,\omega) = -\frac{1}{c^2} \delta |x-y|
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mathematica:

```
Refine[-(c^2/(4 π c r)) Integrate[
  DiracDelta[r - c t] Exp[I ω t], {t, -∞, ∞}], 
    Assumptions -> {r ∈ Reals, c > 0}]
```

The output is

$$-\frac{e^{\frac{i r \omega }{c}}}{4 \pi  r}=-\frac{e^{irk_0}}{4 \pi  r}$$
The extra factor of $c$ is eliminated since the $\delta$ function has an argument of $ct$.

Comment: I am still puzzled by the result. My logic is: $\delta(r-ct) = \delta(t-r/c)$ and therefore by the translation property of the delta function $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i \omega t} \delta (t-r/c) \, dt = e^{i \omega r/c} = e^{i k_0 r}$ ?

Comment: @James: The problem is $f(t)=\delta(r-ct) \neq \delta(t-r/c)$. Rather, $f(t)=\delta(r-ct) = c^{-1}\delta(t-r/c)$.